# Data points rotation in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a list of positions (x;y) to display in a picture box with an angle rotation.

```
For Each pat As cPattern In mPattern
    Dim angle As Double = pat.Angle / 180 * Math.PI

    For Each pos As PointF In pat.Positions
        Dim p As Point = New Point(picPattern.Width \ 2, picPattern.Height \ 2)

        Dim G As Graphics = e.Graphics

        Dim x1 As Single = CSng(pos.X * Math.Cos(angle))
        Dim y1 As Single = CSng(pos.Y * Math.Sin(angle))

        G.DrawEllipse(New Pen(Brushes.Cyan, 2), p.X+x1, p.Y-y1, 3, 3)

    Next
Next
```

with this code I can draw a circle for each position, but only in horizontal mode.

Comment: Can you show a picture of what this looks like un-rotated, and what you want it to look like rotated?  What do you want to rotate around?...the "center of mass" for each set of points?

Comment: I ~think~ you're rotating around the center of the PictureBox?

Comment: thanks for your help
I have a series of real point retrived by a table positioner device, I need to show that points over an image (the image size is less than table).
In second pass I need to rotate that points from a user selected origin point, then I need to retrive new points to move the table positioner.

Comment: So the user picks a new origin.  We shift the points there.  Then should the points be rotated as is by the angle?  Or should they be **centered** on that new origin and rotated and their center?  ...and what is `Positions` in `cPattern`?  Is that an Array or List of Point?

Comment: Hello Idle_ ,
Positions is a generic.list(of pointf), the points should be rotated and centered. the center of rotation is the first point of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to feed the new shifted and rotated points back into your table?

If so, here's an example showing to get the absolute positions of the points, centered and rotated about a passed in position:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Public Class Form1

    Private mPattern As New List(Of cPattern)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Small rectangle with rotation around its center:
        Dim pat As New cPattern
        pat.Angle = 45
        pat.Positions.Add(New Point(35, 35))
        pat.Positions.Add(New Point(10, 10))
        pat.Positions.Add(New Point(60, 10))
        pat.Positions.Add(New Point(60, 60))
        pat.Positions.Add(New Point(10, 60))
        mPattern.Add(pat)
    End Sub

    Private Sub picPattern_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles picPattern.Paint
        Dim G As Graphics = e.Graphics
        Dim center As Point = New Point(picPattern.Width / 2, picPattern.Height / 2)
        For Each pat As cPattern In mPattern
            Dim pts As List(Of Point) = pat.CenterAndRotateAt(center)
            Using cyan As New Pen(Brushes.Cyan, 2)
                For Each pos As Point In pts
                    Dim r As New Rectangle(pos.X, pos.Y, 1, 1)
                    r.Inflate(3, 3)
                    G.DrawEllipse(cyan, r)
                Next
            End Using
        Next
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class cPattern

    Public Angle As Integer
    Public Positions As New List(Of Point)

    Public Function CenterAndRotateAt(ByVal center As Point) As List(Of Point)
        Dim myMatrix As New Matrix
        ' Make the center of rotation for this pattern the new origin:
        myMatrix.Translate(-Me.Positions(0).X, -Me.Positions(0).Y, MatrixOrder.Append)
        ' Rotate the pattern to the desired angle:
        myMatrix.Rotate(Me.Angle, MatrixOrder.Append)
        ' Move the rotated pattern to the desired position:
        myMatrix.Translate(center.X, center.Y, MatrixOrder.Append)

        ' Return the absolute positions of the pattern in the new position with rotation applied:
        ' *** this will NOT change the original points in the pattern! ***
        Dim pts() As Point = Me.Positions.ToArray
        myMatrix.TransformPoints(pts)
        Return New List(Of Point)(pts)
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate about the center of the PictureBox, then use code like this:

```
Private Sub picPattern_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles picPattern.Paint
    Dim G As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Dim center As Point = New Point(picPattern.Width \ 2, picPattern.Height \ 2)
    Using cyan As New Pen(Brushes.Cyan, 2)
        For Each pat As cPattern In mPattern
            G.ResetTransform()
            G.TranslateTransform(center.X, center.Y)
            G.RotateTransform(pat.angle) ' angle in DEGREES!
            For Each pos As PointF In pat.Positions
                Dim r As New Rectangle(pos.X, pos.Y, 1, 1)
                r.Inflate(3, 3)
                G.DrawEllipse(cyan, r)
            Next
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```